# hadoop streaming error,mapreduce with python

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I'm newbie to hadoop environment,Do you have any idea about how to solve this error,or what may be the reason behind this error?

```
hduser@intel-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~/hduser/hadoop$ sudo ./bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.4.jar  -file /home/hduser/map.py  -mapper /home/hduser/map.py -file /home/hduser/red.py -reducer /home/hduser/red.py  -input /home/hduser/tmp/cddb.txt  -output /home/hduser/op1
packageJobJar: [/home/hduser/map.py, /home/hduser/red.py] [] /tmp/streamjob7455767556382290755.jar tmpDir=null
13/06/20 12:43:55 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
13/06/20 12:43:55 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/06/20 12:43:55 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/06/20 12:43:55 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: LocalJobRunner does not support symlinking into current working dir.
13/06/20 12:43:56 INFO streaming.StreamJob: getLocalDirs(): [/tmp/hadoop-root/mapred/local]
13/06/20 12:43:56 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Running job: job_local_0001
13/06/20 12:43:56 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
13/06/20 12:43:56 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
13/06/20 12:43:56 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@e2081
13/06/20 12:43:56 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
13/06/20 12:43:56 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/06/20 12:43:56 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/06/20 12:43:56 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/06/20 12:43:56 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed exec [/home/hduser/hduser/hadoop/./map.py]
13/06/20 12:43:56 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=1/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
13/06/20 12:43:57 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
13/06/20 12:44:02 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: file:/home/hduser/tmp/cddb.txt:0+1205
13/06/20 12:44:03 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 0%
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: Records R/W=9/1
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: MRErrorThread done
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: mapRedFinished
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Records R/W=9/1
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' done.
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@1c84be9
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 1356 bytes
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed exec [/home/hduser/hduser/hadoop/./red.py]
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=1/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: R/W/S=10/0/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hduser/hduser/hadoop/./red.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/hduser/hduser/hadoop/./red.py", line 19, in main
    for similarity, group in groupby(data, itemgetter(0), reverse=True):
TypeError: groupby() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: MRErrorThread done
13/06/20 12:48:11 INFO streaming.PipeMapRed: PipeMapRed failed!
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:260)
13/06/20 12:48:11 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:260)
13/06/20 12:48:12 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
13/06/20 12:48:12 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful. Error: NA
13/06/20 12:48:12 INFO streaming.StreamJob: killJob...
Streaming Command Failed!
```

I'm using hadoop 1.0.4,and wrote map reduce in python(hadoop streaming is used)
.

Comment: Please, post the code in your question's body - code block (no pastebin)

Answer (score 0):

The error is obvious:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hduser/hduser/hadoop/./red.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/hduser/hduser/hadoop/./red.py", line 19, in main
    for similarity, group in groupby(data, itemgetter(0), reverse=True):
TypeError: groupby() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

**groupby** only accepts 2 arguments. Here is the document of [groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).